# How to Implement Caching in JAX-RS

Tags: caching, jax-rs

I am using a Restful webservice for retrieving data from database and returns a JSON response.
I want to cache this webservice call,which means at the startup of the application the webservice shud fetch the result from the database and store it in cache.

On subsequent request,it should read the values from the Cache and not the Database.
Also,when the entry is added/or the existing data is modified,the cache should be refreshed.

I have looked for the HTTP caching code which is written as below:-

```
public class Login_New {
    @GET
    @Path("/dofetch")
    @Produces("application/json")
    public Response getUser() {
        String user = null;
        System.out.println("Inside Login_New");

        ArrayList<User> users = null;

        users = DBConnection.getUser();
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        System.out.println(gson.toJson(users));
        user = gson.toJson(users);

        CacheControl cc = new CacheControl();
        cc.setMaxAge(86400);
        cc.setPrivate(true);

        ResponseBuilder builder = Response.ok(user);
        // return user;
        return builder.build();
    }
}
```

When i am hitting subsequent request i can see from the logs that the request is hitting the database which means Cache isn't working.

Please suggest

Comment: The fact that you are testing the caching by checking if the DB is hit, kinda says that you are missing the point of how the cache control works. The server doesn't cache anything. The browser (or user-agent that supports cc) does the caching. If you are using a browser, then the request should not be made as the browser has the cached object. If you are using a different client that doesn't support HTTP caching, that's the reason the server is being hit.

Comment: so how can i test it..or be sure that the caching is done at the browser end without re-submitting the request again ?